# toggle table row based on unchecked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Not super familiar with frontend, but I have 4 checkboxes I'm using to filter table data. Any number of them can be selected at once.

What I want to accomplish:

1. get all unchecked boxes
2. if no boxes are checked pass (meaning don't hide any rows)
3. if a box is checked, for any box that is NOT checked, exclude the row associated with that unchecked box

This is for a Django app and the table row id  is being generated via database query. The table will have max 100 rows. Per the query I'm executing, any table row will be either: id="audio", id="video", id="writing", id="games"

HTML:

```html
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="music" id="music_filter">
<input type="checkbox" value="video" id="video_filter">
<input type="checkbox" value="writing" id="writing_filter">
<input type="checkbox" value="games" id="games_filter">
</div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    {% for i in query_set %}

    <tbody>
        <tr id="{{i.media_type}}">
            <td>{{some data}}</td>
            <td>{{some other data}}</td>          
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I have jQuery loaded via CDN in the html file and trying this:

JQUERY/JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#music_filter', '#video_filter', '#writing_filter', '#games_filter').on('click',function(){
        var notChecked = $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)");
        if (notChecked.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < notChecked.length; i++) {
                $('#i').toggle();
            };
        }; 
    });
});
```

A little help to see my mistake(s)? Thanks!

Comment: do you mean show/hide `<tr><td></td></tr>` based on which checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to show/hide the row of the table based on the checkboxes, you can do the following:

Add classes to your `<tr>` with the following: music, video, writing, games **AND** add a custom class like `all-genre` . I am guessing the `i.media_type` contains music, video, writing, games so change id to class.

Then use the jquery snippet below:

```
$('#music_filter', '#video_filter', '#writing_filter', '#games_filter').on('click',function(){
        // Check if the checkbox is checked or not
        var notChecked = $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)");
        if (notChecked.length > 0) {
                $(".all-genre").show();
        } else {
            if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                // show the row
                var itemclass = $(this).val(); // value of the checkbox
                $("."+itemclass).show();
            } else {
                // hide the row
                var itemclass = $(this).val();
                $("."+itemclass).hide();
            }
        }
});
```

Though this will work only on the current page. If you are using a pagination, it will not adjust the number of pages since we are not using a get/post request to render new data.

Not tested so you might need to adjust the code to suit your needs.

Comment: edited the answer above to remove redundant code.

Comment: This is closer! However, I don't have a "show all" checkbox. So I want it to show all the data if no boxes are checked. Right now when I load the page it shows all four categories. Then, with your code, if I click/check a filter it hides the appropriate ones, then I click/uncheck that filter and they don't all return. That's why you'll note in my post I wanted to do this by checking if boxes were NOT checked rather than if they were checked.

Comment: What I really need (I think) is this: if more than 0 is checked, then hide any that are not checked.

Comment: you can just wrap this with an if else statement then. first, your if statement, else my if/else

Comment: no need to loop to use show() function.

Comment: though you can change the conditions so that you wont need to add `all-genre` class to the tr element since it does not make sense in english terms. this is just to make it easier to target when adding the show().